# Get and set application's version number in flex using actionScript alone

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, version-control, versioning

Here we want to display Flex Project's version number in an **"About Us"** screen's label.

I want to retrieve the build number and last compiled time stamp dynamically.

I have surfed in net and found in many examples that use ruby or bat coding to do the process of updating a version number and retrieving. Is there any way to update and maintain the version number dynamically(each time I start the debugger) **using actionscript alone** (with out using any other language's coding).

kindly help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't see what good the SDK version is going to give you.  It'll hardly change and even then won't give you any good info.  Wouldn't you rather want the build number of your application and not the SDK's?

Comment: ya ok help me to get the built number of my application..

Comment: i actually need to retrive my project's(which is developed in flex) vertion number. How can i retrive that and store it in a versionLable.text .. kindly help me –

Comment: That all depends on how you're building it.  Are you using Ant? Maven? Any kind of automated process?  Can you modify your question to actually ask the right one?

Comment: Are you referring to SVN Version control or the version system that you follow for your software?

Comment: Check this [link](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=9503). It might help.

Comment: i have surfed in net and i found in many examples they are using ant, ruby , or bat coding to initiate the process of storing version number and retriving. 
is there any way to update the version number dynamically using actionscript alone .. kindly help me

Comment: @all: sorry for not asking the question clearly... is it clear enough now? if you have any doubts plz let me know

Answer (score 12):

You can read your App's descriptor at run-time (for example to get the app's version number) like this:

```
private function getAppVersion():String {
    var appXml:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
    var ns:Namespace = appXml.namespace();
    var appVersion:String = appXml.ns::versionNumber[0];
    return appVersion;
}
```

This blog mantions it:
http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2009/02/quick-tip-display-application-version-in-your-air-app/

Comment: This is for AIR only. Is there another method for browser based Flex apps?

Comment: Do you also use a descriptor file for browser based apps?

Comment: I'll have to check but I don't think so. But the code above uses native application which is an AIR only class.

Comment: AIR applications have an xml descriptor where you put version of __your__ application (not version of the framework). If you want to keep your app's version in one place, simply create a file which will contain a version (kind of a descriptor). If you have a release mechanism, you could add some script to automatically bump the version after the release, and some code to read that version file in runtime to present it to user. That's more or less what's AIR's `app.xml` and `NativeApplication` are for, but in more formalized way, to let App Stores read them.

Comment: Good point. I could embed the application descriptor into the browser build with `[Embed('../../MyProjectDesktop/myproject-descriptor.xml')`  `public var appDescripter:Class` and then pull in the version number from it. Yes, I was not interested in the Flex build number but my application version.

Answer (score 4):

The Flex version number is available, but it's namespaced. You'll have to use the namespace `mx_internal` to be able to access it. Like this:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal;

versionLabel.text = VERSION;
```

Usually you should treat everything Adobe has namespaced 'mx_internal' with care, because they don't guarantee that anything in there will remain the same in future versions of Flex. So you might run into backwards compatibility issues when upgrading your Flex SDK. It seems rather unlikely they would make changes to the VERSION constant though.

Comment: hi RIAstar i think you have given me the flex's version number. But i actually need to retrive my project's(which is developed in flex) vertion number. How can i retrive that and store it in a versionLable.text .. kindly help me

Comment: Indeed your question was quite misleading; especially using 4.5 as an example, which is the version n° of the latest Flex SDK.